# Migrate CSV to content type with paragraphs

Tags: drush, migrations, 9, paragraphs

I'm trying to import a CSV File into Content Types and Paragraphs, using Migrate module (and mainly this tutorial : https://mtech-llc.com/blog/charlotte-leon/migration-csv-data-paragraphs).

For this I have created a custom module in *modules/custom*, and I added the .yml files in *config/install*.

Here's my two .yml (produit_epargne is for the Content Type, and epargne_support is for the Paragraph) :

```
dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - produit_migration
id: produit_epargne
migration_group: produit_group
source:
  plugin: csv
  path: public://csv/test_import_csv_migrate.csv
  ids: 
    [id]
  header_row_count: 1
  delimiter: ';'
  fields:
    - 
      name: id
      label: id
    - 
      name: title
      label: title
    -
      name: field_referent
      label: field_referent
    -
      name: field_fiches_gamme
      label: field_fiches_gamme
    -
      name: field_date_mise_a_jour
      label: field_date_mise_a_jour
process:
  title: title
  field_referent: field_referent
  field_fiches_gamme: field_fiches_gamme
  field_date_mise_a_jour: 
    plugin: format_date
    from_format: Y-m-d
    to_format: Y-m-d
    source: field_date_mise_a_jour
    field_supports/target_id:
      -
        plugin: migration_lookup
        migration: epargne_supports
        no_stub: true
        source: id
      -
        plugin: extract
        index:
          - '0'
    field_supports/target_revision_id:
      -
        plugin: migration_lookup
        migration: epargne_supports
        no_stub: true
        source: id
      -
        plugin: extract
        index:
          - 1
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
  default_bundle: produit_epargne
migration_dependencies:
  required: 
    - epargne_support
  optional: { }
```

```
dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - produit_migration
id: epargne_support
migration_group: produit_group
source:
  plugin: csv
  path: public://csv/test_import_csv_migrate.csv
  header_row_count: 1
  delimiter: ';'
  ids: 
    [id]
  fields:
    -
      name: id
      label: id
    - 
      name: field_nb_fonds_euros
      label: field_nb_fonds_euros
    - 
      name: field_nb_fonds_thematiques
      label: field_nb_fonds_thematiques
    - 
      name: field_nb_support_fcpe
      label: field_nb_support_fcpe
    - 
      name: field_nb_support_uc
      label: field_nb_support_uc
process:
  field_nb_fonds_euros: field_nb_fonds_euros
  field_nb_fonds_thematiques: field_nb_fonds_thematiques
  field_nb_support_fcpe: field_nb_support_fcpe
  field_nb_support_uc: field_nb_support_uc
destination:
  plugin: 'entity_reference_revisions:paragraph'
  default_bundle: epargne_supports
migration_dependencies:
  required:
    - files
  optional: { }
```

But I have two major issues :

1. First, the migration group *produit_group* is not recognized when I run :
   `drush migrate:imports --group produit_group`  which is probably the source of the second issue
2. Second, when I run `drush migrate:imports produit_epargne`, it only creates the content types withtout the paragraphs linked to it.

Does anybody see the problem in my code / configuration ?

Comment: This is an alternative approach: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/278476/paragraphs-from-sub-process/278477#278477

Comment: Does this help ? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/299395/migrate-paragraphs-from-csv-file

Comment: The command is wrong . It should be be `drush migrate:imports --group=produit_group`

Comment: Thanks for your response, unfortunately I still have the same issues. The command does not change the problem either.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my thoughts for your code. Hope it helps!

#1 It should be `drush migrate:import --group=produit_group` instead of `drush migrate:imports --group produit_group`

#2 The paragraph migration name is wrong in the below mapping. It should be
`epargne_support` instead of `epargne_support`

```
field_supports/target_id:
      -
        plugin: migration_lookup
        migration: epargne_supports
        no_stub: true
        source: id
      -
        plugin: extract
        index:
          - '0'
    field_supports/target_revision_id:
      -
        plugin: migration_lookup
        migration: epargne_supports
        no_stub: true
        source: id
      -
        plugin: extract
        index:
          - 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Indeed I have misspelled my migrations name here, but I still have the same issues.
No matter which command I use to run migrations group, I got this error : *You must declare "ids" as a unique array of fields in your source settings.*. In my understanding, it may say that no migration group of this name was find.

Comment: This error looks similar to this one - https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/297975/you-must-declare-ids-as-a-unique-array-of-fields-in-your-source-settings