# How to Migrate paragraphs from CSV one column with multiple values

Tags: migrations, 9, paragraphs

I'm trying to import a CSV file into content type and paragraphs. But I can't get all the values stored in a cell.
Here is my cell:

```
2022-07-13 2022-05-24,2022-06-06 2022-08-08 & 2022-07-16 2022-05-28,2022-06-08 2022-08-09
```

In this example, i have 2 modules:

- The first before the '&'
- The second after the '&'

But there may be more.

I created a custom content type with 2 dates called session.

Each module contains X sessions. each session is separated by ',' and each date of session is separated by ' '.

Here is one line of my csv file:

```
Code_LSO;Titre;Annee_de_creation;Cloture_des_inscriptions;Contenu;Famille_d_emploi;Intervenants;Introduction;Lieu;Nature_des_agents;Nombres_de_jours;Objectifs;Ouvertures_aux_ecoles;Places_disponible;Sous_Direction;Theme;Type;modules

545216;Aptent Decet Exputo Utrum;2022-02-17;2021-10-08;Accumsan amet aptent autem.;famile d’emploi 5;One guy;Abluo decet dolore.;Reims;bocrotoci;684;Ad amet et facilisis feugiat ludus tincidunt vereor.;Abbas immitto imputo usitas.;168;hufriehbfurezbfriezfrugyie;Services administratifs régionaux et interrégionaux;Formation;2022-07-13 2022-05-24,2022-06-06 2022-08-08 & 2022-07-16 2022-05-28,2022-06-08 2022-08-09
```

My migration file for the content_type:

```
uuid: 0178d6be-330f-4df6-aa52-46a0fbf50b82
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: {  }
id: format
class: null
field_plugin_method: null
cck_plugin_method: null
migration_tags:
  - CSV
migration_group: format
label: 'format migration from CSV'
source:
  plugin: csv
  path: /var/www/generatedform.csv
  delimiter: ;
  header_row_count: 1
  ids:
    - Code_LSO
process:
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: formations_et_stage
  title: Titre
  nid: Code_LSO
  field_code_lso: Code_LSO
  field_annee_de_creation/value:
    plugin: format_date
    from_format: Y-m-d
    to_format: Y-m-d
    source: Annee_de_creation
  field_cloture_des_inscriptions/value:
    plugin: format_date
    from_format: Y-m-d
    to_format: Y-m-d
    source: Cloture_des_inscriptions
  field_contenu/format:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: full_html
  field_contenu/value: Contenu
  field_famille_d_emploi: Famille_d_emploi
  field_intervenants: Intervenants
  field_introduction/format:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: full_html
  field_introduction/value: Introduction
  field_lieu:
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: process
      source: Lieu
    -
      plugin: entity_generate
      entity_type: taxonomy_term
      bundle: lieu
      value_key: name
      bundle_key: vid
  field_nature_des_agents: Nature_des_agents
  field_nombres_de_jours: Nombres_de_jours
  field_objectifs/format:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: full_html
  field_objectifs/value: Objectifs
  field_ouvertures_aux_ecoles: Ouvertures_aux_ecoles
  field_places_disponible: Places_disponible
  field_sous_direction: Sous_Direction
  field_theme:
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: process
      source: Theme
    -
      plugin: entity_generate
      entity_type: taxonomy_term
      bundle: theme
      value_key: name
      bundle_key: vid
  field_type:
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: process
      source: Type
    -
      plugin: entity_generate
      entity_type: taxonomy_term
      bundle: type
      value_key: name
      bundle_key: vid
  field_modules:
    plugin: migration_lookup
    migration: migration_paragraph_modules
    source: id
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
migration_dependencies: {migration_paragraph_modules}
```

My migration file for the paragraph:

```
uuid: 93301879-890a-41f8-9024-b3285218b6a7
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: {  }
id: migration_paragraph_modules
class: null
field_plugin_method: null
cck_plugin_method: null
migration_tags:
  - CSV
migration_group: format
label: 'format migration from CSV'
source:
  plugin: csv
  path: /var/www/eng/generatedform.csv
  delimiter: ;
  header_row_count: 1
  ids:
    - Code_LSO
process:
  field_modules:
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: process
      source: modules
    -
      plugin: explode
      delimiter: ' & '
    -
      plugin: sub_process
      process:
        field_session:
          -
            plugin: skip_on_empty
            method: process
            source: modules
          -
            plugin: explode
            delimiter: ','
          -
            plugin: sub_process
            process:
              -
                plugin: explode
                delimiter: ' '
                source: modules
              -
                field_session/date_debut: null
                plugin: extract
                index:
                  - 0
              -
                field_session/date_fin: null
                plugin: extract
                index:
                  - 1
destination:
  plugin: 'entity_reference_revisions:paragraph'
migration_dependencies: null
```

Here is a screenshot of my paragraph:
[image: Paragraph]

I relied on [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/299395/migrate-paragraphs-from-csv-file?newreg=625187ecacc043539c1e4a1eb14ed6ed) and [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/311078/migrate-csv-to-content-type-with-paragraphs) research but it was impossible to get a result.
If someone can help me.
thanks!

Comment: This will not work: `migration_lookup´ uses __one__ ID as source and returns __one__ entity (paragraph or node).

Comment: Using paragraphs (or any other entity reference revision ERR) as migration destination IMHO is generally a bad idea, because paragraphs/ERR revisioning is tied to its parent node, and therefore you can't reliably update existing paragraphs with migrations. Try to use `entity_generate` and create the paragraphs within the node migration.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Hudri
So, i have to try to do all in one migration file ?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_plus/issues/3238343